# How to convert number to string with keeping zero in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to convert for example 03 into "03".
The `(string)03` function returns 3.
Is there a PHP function for that?

Comment: `03` isn't an integer.  The compiler sees the expression as the number 3.

Comment: can you show this fragment `(string)03` as a part of your code?

Comment: 03 known as octal value if it's presented in variable statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding leading 0 in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660683/adding-leading-0-in-php)

Comment: @Max please delete this question if you acknowledge that it is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function num2str($num){
    if($num<10){
        return "0".$num;
    }
    else
    {
        return (string)$num;
    }
}
```

**Note**: You need to change the code accordingly if you want to use negative numbers too.

Comment: It's going to be because the question is a duplicate, I guarantee. The reasoning would be: the question shouldn't exist, therefore, neither should it be indulged with superfluous answers. It's the principle. It's about maintaining higher standards in the site

Answer (score -1):

Conversion function

```
function int2str($num) {
    //match [10, +Infinity]
    if ($num >= 10) return $num;
    //match [0, 9]
    if ($num >= 0 && $num < 10) return '0' . $num;
    //match [-9, -1]
    if ($num > -10 && $num < 0) return '-0' . (-1 * $num);
    //else match [-Infinity, -10]
    return "$num";
};
```

Comment: I like to know why people downvote my answers so I can get better

Comment: see my comment below

Comment: How would I know it's a duplicate?. You should downvote the question or remove it even. Not go about downvoting anwswers

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'm tempted. You shouldn't waste your time on questions that are duplicates. Read the comments actively. A question pertaining to leading zeros in PHP was asked this week already, and there are always going to be these questions. The longer you stick around the more you'll notice it ;)